# В каких случаях правильно создавать вложенный тип?

Tags: c#, .net

Например, у майков есть DataTable, DataRow, DataColumn, которые оформлены в виде отдельных классов. Почему майки пошли этим путем, а не сделали типы вложенными один в другой? Ведь, они взаимосвязаны между собой. Или это чему-то противоречит?

Comment: [When and why to use Nested Classes?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/314043)

Comment: @Grundy а почему не ответ?

Comment: @Bald, потому что перевести надо :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внутренние классы по сути ничем не отличаются от внутренних, приватных методов.

Метод делают внутренним потому, что он не имеет смысла вне контекста конкретной имплементации данного класса, так что смысла пользоваться им кому-то снаружи нет никакого. Точно так же и классы, которые нужны/интересны лишь как деталь имплементации внешнего класса, стоит спрятать внутрь данного класса, чтобы они не были никому видны и не засоряли область видимости.

Канонический пример — имплементация различных итераторов и энумераторов. За пределами внешнего класса обычно имеет смысл лишь интерфейс, поэтому конкретный класс, имплементирующий `IEnumerable<T>`, остаётся «за кадром».

---

В случае `DataTable`, `DataRow` и `DataColumn` работа с каждым из них имеет смысл для нас, пользователей `DataTable`. Поэтому данные классы не помещены внутрь `DataTable`, а лежат снаружи.

---

В случае открытого внутреннего класса, внешний класс служит по сути пространством имён. Технически необходимость такой структуры классов может возникнуть в связи с тем, что внутренние классы имеют доступ к закрытым полям объемлющих классов, и тем самым представляют собой аналог `friend`-классов из C++. Однако такая необходимость может означать ошибку в дизайне: отдельные, доступные внешнему миру сущности должны общаться друг с другом через открытые интерфейсы.

---

<sup>Ответ основан на [этом ответе](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/314044/6802) с en.SO</sup>